# Laravel many-to-many query with three keys?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

Im having trouble fully understanding laravels relationship system. I want to get a variable of persons that plays in a certain band in a certain festival.

Here are my tables:

Bandstruckture table:

```
id, festival_id, band_id, person_id
```

Person table:

```
id, firstname, lastname
```

Festival table:

```
id, festivalname
```

Band table:

```
id, bandname
```

In my Festival model, i have this:

```
    public function persons() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Person','fs_festival_persons','festival_id','person_id');
}
```

To list all persons in the festival, i use this code in the controller:

```
$persons = $festival->persons()->get();
```

And it works fine. (retrieveing from a person-festival pivot table). But Im unsure how to do some laravel magic to make a list of people derivated from Bandstructure, where i retrieve all person_id's when i have festival_id, and band_id, and make it into a person-array. Any ideas? Ive tried alot and googled but cant find any examples that work for me.

Comment: I can manually make a query like this: 
$persons = DB::table('fs_persons') ->join('fs_bandstruktur', 'person_id','=','fs_persons.id') ->where('band_id', '=', $band_id) ->get();

That gets the result I want, but was hoping for some laravel magic

Comment: Did you tryed the eloquent method "wherePivot()" ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try ***wherePivot()*** eloquent function like this:

In your Bandstruckture model:

```
<?php
class Bandstruckture extends Eloquent {

    public function persons()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Person')->withPivot(['festival_id', 'band_id']);
    }

}
```

And use this like:

```
$persons = $festival->persons()->wherePivot('festival_id', $festival_id)->wherePivot('band_id', $band_id)->get();
```